# How would I be able to target a specific table to manipulate it?

Tags: javascript, css, button, foreach, html-table

[Html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjWxZ.png)

Browser view of html page:

[image]

[CSS page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVMtD.png)

I'm trying to target a specific table when I click the buttons. But the function I have set up effects all of them, even the table in the middle. I figured table.children[0].childElementCount > 10 would only effect the first and the third table since there the one that have more then 10 rows. Would any one know how I can target an individual table that has a more then 10 rows?

Please let me know if my question makes sense and if I need to provide additional information.

**Javascript**

```
/* ==========================================================================
                    ShowDebug constructor
========================================================================== */

var ShowDebug = function () {
this.tables = document.querySelectorAll('.tbl_List');

this.counters = {
    min: 1,
    max: 5
}

this.rule = document.styleSheets[0].rules[0]
this.appendElements();
}

/* ==========================================================================
                   ShowDebug Inherited methods
  ========================================================================== */

ShowDebug.prototype = {
// Create button to collopase table items
createLessBtn() {
    var lessBtn = document.createElement("button");
    lessBtn.className = "btn";
    lessBtn.textContent = "Less";
    lessBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "showDebug.showLess();");
    return lessBtn
},

// Create button to expand table items
createMoreBtn() {
    var moreBtn = document.createElement("button");
    moreBtn.className = "btn";
    moreBtn.textContent = "More";
    moreBtn.setAttribute("onclick", "showDebug.showMore();");
    return moreBtn
},

// Append elements to the tables
appendElements() {

    console.log(document.styleSheets[0].rules[0])

    this.tables.forEach(function (table) {
        if (table.children[0].childElementCount > 10) {
            let itemCounter = document.createElement('span')
            itemCounter.className = "item-counter"
            itemCounter.innerHTML = ` 1 - 10 of ${table.children[0].childElementCount} items`
            table.children[0].appendChild(itemCounter);
            table.children[0].appendChild(this.createLessBtn());
            table.children[0].appendChild(this.createMoreBtn());


        }
    }, this)
},

// Collaspe table items
showLess() {
    this.tables.forEach(function (table, index) {
        if (table.children[0].childElementCount > 10) {

            if (index === 0) {
                console.log("less");
                showDebug.counters.max = showDebug.counters.max - 5;
                showDebug.rule.selectorText = "table tr:nth-of-type(" + showDebug.counters.min + "n+" + showDebug.counters.max + ")";
            }


        }
    })
},

// Expand table items
showMore() {
    this.tables.forEach(function (table, index) {
        if (table.children[0].childElementCount > 10) {

            if (index === 0) {
                console.log("more");
                showDebug.counters.max = showDebug.counters.max + 5;
                showDebug.rule.selectorText = "table tr:nth-of-type(" + showDebug.counters.min + "n+" + showDebug.counters.max + ")";
            }

        }
    })
}

 }

 var showDebug = new ShowDebug();
```

**CSS**

```
table tr:nth-of-type(1n+5) {
display: none;
}

table {
width: 100%;
}

/* .hide:nth-of-type(1n+1) {
display: none;
background: red;
} */
```

Comment: You should not have any images of text. All relevant code should be in the question or pruned down.

Answer (score 1):

`.querySelectorAll()` will create a collection (as you know). But since you are selecting a table using its `id` attribute, there will only be one. HTML `id` attributes must be unique on the page.  Therefore, `.querySelector()` is the correct solution.

**Change:**

`document.querySelectorAll('#tbl_List');`

**To**

`document.querySelector('#tbl_List');`

Then, refactor to remove the `forEach()` loops. There will only be one table rather than a NodeList.

**Edit**

You should be aware that there are several ways to collect all the tables. You can use `document.querySelectorAll('table')` and that will return a collection of all tables. (you don't need id's or class names just for selection).

Based upon your comment below: Please investigate event delegation:
https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Given a table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th></th><th></th></tr>
  <thead>
  <tbody> /** <-- BIND YOUR CLICK HANDLER HERE !!!! **/
    <tr><td></td><td><button>Less</button><button>More</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><button>Less</button><button>More</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><button>Less</button><button>More</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td><td><button>Less</button><button>More</button></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice where to bind the click handler. Binding it there allows you to retrieve the cell, row or entire table body no matter what cell the button is in that gets clicked. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ah, thank you for bringing to my awareness my use of Id's for selecting the tables. I've updated it to class. I want to be able to manipulate the other tables as well. But I want the buttons(Less and More) which are is child of that table to only target the table there under.